# Generic Enum Parser without unchecked warning

Tags: java, generics, enums, warnings

How to remove `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` in the following code?

```
public <T extends Enum<T>> T getEnum( String key, T dflt ) {
   final String value = properties.getProperty( key, dflt.name());
   @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
   final Class<T> clazz = (Class<T>)dflt.getClass();
   return Enum.valueOf( clazz, value );
}
```

Comment: This line: final Class<T> clazz = (Class<T>)dflt.getClass(); just prevent for a warning. You cannot remove that because this cast is not safe

Comment: not quite clear what you are asking. Do you want the code to compile without warnings and also without having the SuppressWarnings annotation?

Comment: But I think that you can also use: final Class<T> clazz = dflt.getDeclaringClass();

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All `Enum<E>` subclasses have a method that returns its `Class` that is properly parameterized.

```
public <T extends Enum<T>> T getEnum(String key, T dflt) {
    final String value = properties.getProperty(key, dflt.name());
    final Class<T> clazz = dflt.getDeclaringClass();
    return Enum.valueOf(clazz, value);
}
```

EDIT: **Your previous solution is WRONG, not just bad style.**

> ```
> public final Class<E> getDeclaringClass()
> ```
>
> Returns the Class object corresponding to this enum constant's enum type. Two enum constants e1 and e2 are of the same enum type if and only if e1.getDeclaringClass() == e2.getDeclaringClass(). **(The value returned by this method may differ from the one returned by the Object.getClass() method for enum constants with constant-specific class bodies.)**

`Enum.valueOf(Class, String)` may complain if the `Class` passed in is the `Class` for "enum constants with constant-specific class bodies". `Class.isEnum()` will return `false` for those classes.